# How to use -I{} with xargs' with an -n greater than 1?

Tags: xargs

I have a very large number of files (tens of thousands) that I need to `grep` through for a specific string. A small handful of the files have spaces in them. There are so many files the process creation overhead `-n1` is actually bigger than the file search itself.

This works, but is unusably slow:

```
cat filelist | xargs -I{} grep mystring '{}'
```

So, I want to pass 1000 arguments to each `grep` instance, like this:

```
cat filelist | xargs -n1000 -I{} grep mystring '{}'
```

**But this doesn't work**. It seems the `{}` only works when `-n` = 1?!

Example:

```
Too many processes, correct output:
$ seq 1 10 | xargs -I{} -n1 echo "<{}>"
<1>
<2>
<3>
<4>
<5>
<6>
<7>
<8>
<9>
<10>
```

```
Good number of processes, and... what?
$ seq 1 10 | xargs -I{} -n2 echo "<{}>"
<{}> 1 2
<{}> 3 4
<{}> 5 6
<{}> 7 8
<{}> 9 10
```

Maybe I can use `find` instead.

Comment: You can also think about grep with the recursive option. That's just one process then.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, `-I` only works with for one argument at a time. With `-I`, the input is also parsed into arguments in a different way than without (using `-n` or not).

With `-I{}` you get a word for each non-empty line (except it's still possible to embed a newline by quoting it with backslash), with the leading, but not trailing blank characters (the list of which varies with the implementation and locale for some) removed. Quotes (`"`, `'` and `\` are still processed, in a different way from `sh`'s though).

Without `-I{}`, words are whitespace (at least SPC, TAB and NL) delimited, and quotes processed.

Compare:

```
$ printf ' a "b c" \n' | xargs -n1 printf '<%s>\n'
<a>
<b c>
$ printf ' a "b c" \n' | xargs -I{} printf '<%s>\n' {}
<a b c >
```

IMO, `xargs` is a bit of a mess, the only reliable/useful ways to use it are with the `-0` and `-d` GNU extensions.

If you want to run a command with more than one argument at a time and use a different place-holder for each, best is to use `sh`:

```
xargs < filelist -r -n2 sh -c 'printf "1: %s\n2: %s\n" "$1" "$2"' sh
```

Here, `xargs` passes 2 arguments at a time to `sh`, and `sh` does the place holding with `"$1"` and `"$2"` (see also `"$@"` to pass all arguments at once).

That's with the default word tokenising of `xargs`. If `filelist` is meant to contain one file per line, you'd use GNU `xargs`'s `-d '\n'`.

For your `grep` example, you don't need `-n` nor `-I` though, just:

```
xargs < filelist grep mystring
```

Then `xargs` will pass as many arguments as possible to `grep` (the arguments are added at the end). We can do without `-r` here (a GNU extension) as if `filelist` is all blank, still running `grep` without file arguments (which `-r` prevents) should be harmless as it would search for mystring at the end of `filelist`.

You may however want to use the `-H` option of GNU `grep`, or run it as:

```
xargs < filelist grep mystring /dev/null
```

to make sure that `grep` always prints the file name when it finds a match even if `filelist` contains only one word.

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

`xargs -I '{}' -n 1 -P 1000 grep mystring '{}' < file_list.txt`

- **-I** replace-str
- **-n** max-args
- **-P** max-procs

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel has fixed this issue. -X will include the context:

```
$ seq 1 10 | parallel -j1 -qX echo "<{}>"
<1> <2> <3> <4> <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
```

-m will not:

```
$ seq 1 10 | parallel -j1 -qm echo "<{}>"
<1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10>
```